# Aspose: Text after Ampersand(&) not seen while setting the page header

Tags: grails, groovy, header, aspose, aspose.pdf

I encountered a problem with setting the page header text containing ampersand like ‘a&b’. The text after ‘&’ disappears in the pdf maybe because it is the reserved key in **Aspose**. My code looks like this:

```
 PageSetup pageSetup = workbook.getWorksheets().get(worksheetName).getPageSetup();
 //calling the function
  setHeaderFooter(pageSetup, parameters, criteria)

 //function for setting header and footer
 def setHeaderFooter(PageSetup pageSetup, parameters, criteria = [:])
    {
       def selectedLoa=getSelectedLoa(parameters)
       if(selectedLoa.length()>110){
        String firstLine = selectedLoa.substring(0,110);
        String secondLine = selectedLoa.substring(110);
        if(secondLine.length()>120){
            secondLine = secondLine.substring(0,122)+"...."
        }
        selectedLoa = firstLine+"\n"+secondLine.trim();
    }
    def periodInfo=getPeriodInfo(parameters, criteria)
    def reportingInfo=periodInfo[0]
    def comparisonInfo=periodInfo[1]
    def benchmarkName=getBenchmark(parameters)
    def isNonComparison = criteria.isNonComparison?
    criteria.isNonComparison:false

    def footerInfo="&BReporting Period:&B " + reportingInfo+"\n"
    if (comparisonInfo && !isNonComparison){
        footerInfo=footerInfo+"&BComparison Period:&B " +comparisonInfo+"\n"
    }
    if (benchmarkName){
        footerInfo+="&BBenchmark:&B "+benchmarkName
    }
   //where I encounterd the issue,selectedLoa contains string with ampersand
    pageSetup.setHeader(0, pageSetup.getHeader(0) + "\n&\"Lucida Sans,Regular\"&8&K02-074&BPopulation:&B "+selectedLoa)

    //Insertion of footer
    pageSetup.setFooter(0,"&\"Lucida Sans,Regular\"&8&K02-074"+footerInfo)
    def downloadDate = new Date().format("MMMM dd, yyyy")
    pageSetup.setFooter(2,"&\"Lucida Sans,Regular\"&8&K02-074" + downloadDate)

    //Insertion of logo
    try{
        def bucketName = parameters.containsKey('printedRLBucketName')?parameters.get('printedRLBucketName'):null
        def filePath = parameters.containsKey('printedReportLogo')?parameters.get('printedReportLogo'): null

        // Declaring a byte array
        byte[] binaryData

        if(!filePath || filePath.contains("null") || filePath.endsWith("null")){
            filePath = root+"/images/defaultExportLogo.png"
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath))
            binaryData = is.getBytes()
        }else {
            AmazonS3Client s3client = amazonClientService.getAmazonS3Client()
            S3Object object = s3client.getObject(bucketName, filePath)

            // Getting the bytes out of input stream of S3 object
            binaryData = object.getObjectContent().getBytes()
        }

        // Setting the logo/picture in the right section (2) of the page header
        pageSetup.setHeaderPicture(2, binaryData);

        // Setting the script for the logo/picture
        pageSetup.setHeader(2, "&G");

        // Scaling the picture to correct size
        Picture pic = pageSetup.getPicture(true, 2);
        pic.setLockAspectRatio(true)
        pic.setRelativeToOriginalPictureSize(true)
        pic.setHeight(35)
        pic.setWidth(Math.abs(pic.getWidth() * (pic.getHeightScale() / 100)).intValue());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

In this case, I get only ‘a’ in the pdf header all other text after ampersand gets disappeared. Please suggest me with a solution for this. I am using aspose 18.2

Answer (score 0):

We have added header on a PDF page with below code snippet but we did not notice any problem when ampersand sign is included in header text.

```
// open document
Document document = new Document(dataDir + "input.pdf");
// create text stamp
TextStamp textStamp = new TextStamp("a&bcdefg");
// set properties of the stamp
textStamp.setTopMargin(10);
textStamp.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.Center);
textStamp.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.Top);

// set text properties
textStamp.getTextState().setFont(new FontRepository().findFont("Arial"));
textStamp.getTextState().setFontSize(14.0F);
textStamp.getTextState().setFontStyle(FontStyles.Bold);
textStamp.getTextState().setFontStyle(FontStyles.Italic);
textStamp.getTextState().setForegroundColor(Color.getGreen());

// iterate through all pages of PDF file
for (int Page_counter = 1; Page_counter <= document.getPages().size(); Page_counter++) {
        // add stamp to all pages of PDF file
        document.getPages().get_Item(Page_counter).addStamp(textStamp);
}
// save output document
document.save(dataDir + "TextStamp_18.8.pdf");
```

Please ensure using Aspose.PDF for Java 18.8 in your environment. For further information on adding page header, you may visit [Add Text Stamp in the Header or Footer section](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfjava/Add+Text+Stamp+in+the+Header+or+Footer+section+of+the+PDF+file).

In case you face any problem while adding header, then please share your code snippet and generated PDF document with us via Google Drive, Dropbox etc. so that we may investigate it to help you out.

**PS**: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: I have updated the code snipped in the question. And I have not used TextStamp, instead i am using PageSetup. Does that make any difference? Also I will need some time updating to 18.8. For now, i need to hotfix the issue.

Comment: @Amjad Sahi Thank you Amjad! it helped a bit. When the text is like ‘a&bcdefgh’, replacing the ‘&’ in text with ‘&&’ fixes the issue. But when the text is like ‘a&b&c&d&e’, i.e., when the text has multiple ampersands, it does not work. It only works for the first occurred ampersand. Can you also provide some light on this?

Comment: Please try our latest version/fix (e.g v18.8), it will fix your issue as I tested.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, "&" is a reserved word when inserting headers/footers in MS Excel spreadsheet via Aspose.Cells APIs. To cope with your issue, you got to place another ampersand to paste the "& (ampersand)" in the header string. See the sample code for your reference:
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook();

        Worksheet ws = wb.getWorksheets().get(0);
        ws.getCells().get("A1").putValue("testin..");

        String headerText="a&&bcdefg";
        PageSetup pageSetup = ws.getPageSetup();
        pageSetup.setHeader(0, headerText);

        wb.save("f:\\files\\out1.xlsx");
        wb.save("f:\\files\\out2.pdf");
```

Hope this helps a bit.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.